# c# asp.net form data with individual user

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am interested in asp.net c# and wondering what is normal practice in following case.
basically, this is what I want:

i have a webpage with some forms, user can enter data and calculations are done on server. the next time after user logs in, his/her last run data will be populated into those forms.

there could be many users, but each of them has to register and log into site, which means they all use same forms, but the data they enter is different.

any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: Have you heard about `sessions` in C#??

Comment: yes, but sessions is terminated each time and i need data user entered to be saved somewhere and display next time when user logs in

Comment: @user2324644 - have you heard about `cookies` in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common practice here is to use a database table associated to each user. You can add a save button to the form that triggers the insert into the database for example.

Persisting this data with client side storage (HTML5) will not work if the user uses multiple devices. Regarding the server side storage options, the database seems more appropriate. You can't use sessions because they will expire,

Comment: is there any other way on server beside using database?  can we use a file let's say a simple txt file instead? because information user entered is not large in size.

Comment: You can use files, but this is what databases were made for: saving, updating and retrieving data on the server. Files are inefficient and harder to manage, they will cause you *much* more problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the user entered data to the local storage (concept introduced in HTML 5). The data will be saved to the local client machine using this. While loading the page check whether any data stored in local storage and if any stored then load that data to the UI. All these needs to be implemented client side (JavaScript). But this will help you only if the user uses the same system.

If the user uses multiple system and even at that time he or she needs to be loaded with their previous data then you had to create a table in the DB named userpreferance and save all the user entred value with their login id. Then load that data to the UI back when they are loggin again.

Using these 2 methods you can maintain the user's lastly entered values.

Comment: i wish i could give both of you credit, but system only allows one given.